# Bind property of root to value of child element in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I'm not too used to WPF, so this is probably something easy, but I've been struggling with it for a couple hours and can't seem to get how to properly do it.

Say I have a `BaseUserControl` descending from `UserControl` with a dependency property `Text`.

Then in XAML I'm creating a BaseUserControl descendant. I want that property `Text` to be bound to a control defined in that descendant. Say:

```
<base:BaseUserControl
         ... all namespaces ...
         xmlns:base="clr-namespace:MyControlsBase"
         x:Class="Test.MyTestControl"
         Text="{Binding ElementName=MyTextBox, Path=Text}"
    <TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" Text="MyText" />
</base:BaseUserControl>
```

For some reason, I can't get the `MyTextBox` to update the `Text` property on the control itself.

If I add a:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=MyTextBox, Path=Text}" />
```

Anywhere inside the control, the textblock shows the correct TextBox value so the binding definition doesn't seem to be the problem.

I have something else which shows the value of `Text` in that control... say something like:

```
<Window>
  <StackPanel>
    <test:MyTestControl x:Name="MyControl" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=MyControl, Path=Text}" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

If I update the Text property on MyControlBase from any other means (codebehind, or whatever), it works, and I see the text changed on the textblock... but it doesn't work seem to update when the TextBox inside itself is updated.

Are there any limitations on binding to properties when you are inheriting a control?

*PS: the code is obviously artificial and boilerplated for this question*

**Note**: there is obviously something wrong with the binding on that property, since on the trace window, when creating the control, I get a:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference     'ElementName=MyTextBox'. BindingExpression:Path=Text; DataItem=null; target element is 'MyTestControl' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

But it only happens for the `MyTestControl's property, and not for any other binding to the same property inside the XAML.

Comment: it's really weird. The similar binding scenario for such as any other container (not a UserControl) would work perfectly. While the reason is still unclear, you can try binding in the reverse direction (the target is `MyTextBox` and the source is the usercontrol, of course TwoWay binding mode should be used).

Comment: That wouldn't work since I can't assign a name to it (`BaseUserControl` would be abstract). I could do a `FindAncestor` for type `BaseUserControl` but that wouldn't be general (it could find other `BaseUserControls` inbetween)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that the MyTextBox hasn't been initialized when the BaseUserControl initializes itself and tries to bind with the Text property of the MyTextBox. At this stage, the MyTextBox doesn't exist, as a result you get the 'System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find ***SOURCE*** for binding with reference'.

You can bind in code-behind after the InitializeComponent() in the CTOR of your MyTestControl.

```
public MyTestControl()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   Binding b = new Binding("Text");
   b.Source = MyTextBox;
   SetBinding(TextProperty, b);
}
```

Comment: This works, and I'm marking it as the answer... however, I've tried the same but using `b.ElementName = "MyTextBox"` instead of `b.Source = MyTextBox` (after the object is constructed) and it doesn't work from codebehind either (same problem, says `Cannot find source with ElementName='MyTextBox'`).

This is definitely not critical, but I'd like to understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: Just tested in .NET framework 4 and 4.5, b.ElementName = "MyTextBox" works as fine as the b.Source. Don't know why yours doesn't work.