# IValueConverter doesn't execute

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, converters

I have this XAML Code (**ErdMenuItem.xaml**):

```
<UserControl x:Class="ErdBuilder.ErdMenuItem"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:erdBuilder="clr-namespace:ErdBuilder"
  x:Name="UserControl">  

   <UserControl.Resources>
      <erdBuilder:ByteImageConverter x:Key="imageConverter" />
   </UserControl.Resources>

   <Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource imageConverter}, ElementName=UserControl, Path=Icon}" />
</UserControl>
```

If I write:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource imageConverter}, ElementName=UserControl, Path=Icon}" />
```

Then the Converter will not be executed - I use Breakpoints in the Converter. But if I use this:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource imageConverter}}" />
```

Then the Converter will be executed. **Icon** is a Dependency Property of type **string**. I dont know why the Converter will not be executed as far as I add the DependencyProperty which should bring in the Value which I want to convert. Any Ideas ?

The Icon is here (**ErdMenuItem.xaml.cs**):

```
namespace ErdBuilder
{
    public partial class ErdMenuItem
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IconProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Icon", typeof(string), typeof(ErdMenuItem), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure));
        public string Icon
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(IconProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IconProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot see property Icon on UserControl, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Maximus It's an inherited from UserControl class ErdMenuItem

Comment: As far as your code is concerned, everything seems fine by first glance. I suggest you to take a look at output window & post your converter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because there's no data in `DataContext`. The binding expression returns value of the current `DataContext`. You can set `DataContext` for `Image` by using `{Binding Converter={StaticResource imageConverter}, Path=Icon}` expression or set it for the root element (`UserControl` in your case). This option is better, as you can use `RelativeSource` expression to avoid using explicit names.

```
<UserControl x:Class="ErdBuilder.ErdMenuItem"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:erdBuilder="clr-namespace:ErdBuilder"
  x:Name="UserControl"
  DataContext="{Binding RelateSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
```

Comment: I've added >> DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" << and changed the Binding from >> Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource IconConverter}, ElementName=UserControl, Path=Icon}" << to >> Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource IconConverter}, Path=Icon}" << - that works well. Thank you so much!

Comment: "The binding expression returns value of the current DataContext." - I don't think so. He's binding directly against UserControl by using `ElementName`. If you set DataContext, you'd have to reference it through `{Binding Converter={StaticResource imageConverter}, ElementName=UserControl, Path=DataContext.Icon}`

Comment: ElementName uses LogicalTree so it can effortlessly move between elements without specified DataContext. What is more, UserControl is placed in Window and it derives that Window's DataContext, by default. Basically, under the hood DataContext was set but it did not play any role, anyway. ElementName does not use DataContext, it uses tree.

Comment: >> Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource IconConverter}, ElementName=UserControl, Path=DataContext.Icon}" << does not work.

Comment: This happened to me on a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26814668/bind-property-of-root-to-value-of-child-element-in-xaml . It seemed to work for others though so I still don't know what's wrong. **Edit**: not exactly the same, I was trying to bind a property on the root to a inner element

Comment: @ChrisEelmaa You're wrong. He's trying to bind to the property of the root element, which is UserControl (it's a name). If Icon property belonged to other class, you would be right.

Comment: @Maximus I agree, I've misunderstood question and have thought that the first line (which uses ElementName) was working.

Comment: Now my Command Binding doesnt work anymore as long as I use the DataContext ('DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"').

Comment: How can I move the "DataContext" Property in "UserControl" to "Image" ? And how should I implement it ?